# the global object of closure

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is something very basic in JS I am not sure about. So I would like to ask.

The global object is `window` (or `global` of course for node.js). So we can for example get the variable's value by its name `window[myVariableName]`.

The question is how can I do it with a local variable of a closure?

```
function myFunction()
{
  // some code here    
  console.log(global_object[myVariableName]);
}
```

And may be even to get the variable's value by name, when the variable is global for the current closure but doesn't belong to `window` object.

From what I know about JS and how it works - it's impossible.

By the way, it's a very popular interview question how to get the variable's value by its name and it's never mentioned that the variable is global :).

Answer (score 4):

```
eval('var value = ' + myVariableName + ';');
console.log(value);
```

Yeah, eval is evil but it **is** a solution (for a weird task though).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the all evil `eval`

```
function test() {
 var a = 5;
 var myname = "a";
 console.log(eval(myname))
}

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable can't be "global" to a closure.
It's either global or it's not.

If it's not, then it's within a function scope.

If it's within a function's scope, then the only way to get it, once you're outside of that function, is to have made it a property which you return from the function, or to append it to an object/array, which you passed into the function, or to create a function INSIDE of the function, which returns that variable...

```
// modifying an object
var my_func = function (obj) {
    var hidden = 1;
    obj.hidden = hidden;
};

var my_obj = {};
my_func(my_obj);
my_obj.hidden; // 1

// returning a function
var my_func = function () {
    var a = 1,
        b = 2,
        c = 3,

        get_a = function () { return a; },
        get_b = function () { return b; },
        get_c = function () { return c; };


    return { a : get_a, b : get_b, c : get_c };
};


var my_obj = my_func();
my_obj.a(); // 1
my_obj.b(); // 2
my_obj.c(); // 3
```

If you would prefer to do this by "name", then you'd create one object in your closure, and you would create a function which took a string and looked for properties of that object, by name.

```
// get property by name

var my_func = function () {
    var properties = {
        a : 1,
        b : 2,
        c : 3
    };


    return {
        get : function (name) {
            return properties[name]; // returns undefined if it doesn't exist
        }
    }; 
};


var my_obj = my_func();
my_obj.get("a"); // 1
my_obj.get("b"); // 2
```

Now you can.

PS: `eval();` isn't always guaranteed to work in the way that's described above.
For example, in the future, `eval` should run in its own scope and have no access to the calling function's scope (the same way building `new Function("...");` works).

### ***EDIT***

To take this one step further, to better answer your question about `"global"` as it pertains to scope:

```
window.bob = "Bob";

var outer_A = function () {
        var mid_A = function () {
            var inner_A = function () {
                console.log("INNER-A");
                console.log("bob = "  + bob );
                console.log("doug = " + doug);
            };

            inner_A();
        };

        mid_A();
    },

    outer_B = function () {
        var mid_B = function () {
                var doug = "Doug",

                    inner_B = function () {
                        console.log("INNER-B");
                        console.log("bob = "  + bob );
                        console.log("doug = " + doug);
                    };

                inner_B();
            },

            mid_C = function () {
                var inner_C = function () {
                    console.log("INNER-C");
                    console.log("bob = "  + bob );
                    console.log("doug = " + doug);
                };

                inner_C();
            };

        mid_B();
        mid_C();
    };


outer_A();
outer_B();
```

What does this get you?
You should end up with a printout that looks like:

```
/*

INNER-A
bob = Bob
doug = undefined

INNER-B
bob = Bob
doug = Doug

INNER-C
bob = Bob
doug = undefined

*/
```

Why would you end up with that?
Well, quite simply, because you have branching function-scopes.
`doug` is defined inside of `mid_B`.
Any functions which are created inside of `mid_B` can potentially access `doug`.
No functions created outside of `mid_B` can access `doug`.

When `inner_C` is asked to log `doug`, first it checks if `doug` exists in its own function.
If not, then it checks to see if it exists in its parent's function-scope (`mid_C`).
If not, then it checks to see if it exists in ***its*** parent's function-scope (`outer_B`).
If not, then it checks to see if it exists in ***its*** parent's function-scope (`window`).
If you make it all the way back to `window`, it has no parent function-scope...
...so if it's not even in `window`, then set the value to `undefined`.

Meanwhile, `inner_B` can't find `doug`, so it checks `mid_B` and finds `doug`.

This doesn't make `doug` "global".
It makes it `in-scope`.

"global" would be if `outer_A`, `mid_A`, `inner_A`, `outer_B`, `mid_B`, `inner_B`, `mid_C` and `inner_C` all had access...

...that would be `bob`.
`bob` is global.

It's global because it's attached to the window object (or defined as a `var` in the `global-scope`, which works pretty much the same way except when using `delete`).
And because all child functions have function-scopes which lead back to `window`, all functions can access anything defined as a property/var of `window` (unless there's a variable further up the scope-chain with the same name, at which point it picks the first one it hits).

This is what `global` means, and why `doug` is not a `global` variable in this example.

Comment: Concerning your comment: **A variable can't be "global" to a closure.
It's either global or it's not.**. What about: `function outer(){function mid(){var a=1; function inner(){console.log(a);};};}`? Here `a` is global to a closure of function `inner`, isn't it?

Comment: `function` is a keyword: `if|else|break|delete|var|function|while|do` etc, are parts of the language itself. As for cases like `window["bob"] = "Bob"; (function () { (function () { console.log(bob); }()); }());` this is scope-chain resolution which leads back to `window`, if there are no variables with that name, before reaching `window`. ***EDIT*** No. `a` is not `"global"`. `a` is part of the scope-chain-resolution. `global` means "Any piece of the program, anywhere, can access it, period, if the scope-chain-resolution goes all the way back to the top before hitting a var with the same name"

Comment: @Alexander have a look at my edited answer.  This is why it's not "global".

Comment: Ok, so I was confused with the terminology here :). Thanks!